# Not being able to "POST" data

Tags: javascript, html, api, http, put

i am trying to insert data into a local server but the data is not being inserted. I am using the JSON server package, and i am trying to insert to the endpoint: './users'.

Here is the code:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("Slot", JSON.stringify(slot.value))
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/users', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            "name": window.sessionStorage.getItem("name"),
            "age": window.sessionStorage.getItem("age"),
            "carBrand": window.sessionStorage.getItem("carBrand"),
            "details": window.sessionStorage.getItem("details"),
        }
    }).then((response) => {
       console.log(response)
    }).then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
})
```

This seems to be working fine, cause once i submit the form, an instance of an object is created, but the data is not being pulled to the API and i also logged the response coming from the server, and it all seems to be working fine.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions, and edit this question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow, or it may be closed. Get in the habit of debugging your own code.  Look in the Chrome network tab for network errors, and look at your local server output for errors. You're asking about json-server, but you don't show us anything about it, like your `db.json` file. The question is confusing, because you say "all seems to be working fine" without asking a question.

Comment: I think I have found your problem: You are setting the body to an object. That is not allowed by most browsers (I think). The fetch API will convert your body to `"[object Object]"`. If your server can parse JSON, use `JSON.stringify(object)` in the body field.